# Run 'mongod.exe' with '--dbpath' containing the Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: mongodb, cyrillic

I want to run MongoDB to save data into user AppData (on Windows).

```
mongod.exe --dbpath "C:/Users/%User%/AppData/Local/%MyFolder%"
```

But in my case `%User%` may contain Cyrillic.
Thus `mongod.exe` does not start with an error

```
... [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory C:/Users/%User%/AppData/Local/%MyFolder% not found., terminating ...
```

While this folder exists.

Comment: How starting it with these options. Maybe someone knows a way to do it.

Comment: Can you add an example of a `dbpath` that doesn't work (i.e. with `%USER%` and `%MyFolder%` placeholders expanded to their values with Cyrillic characters)?

Comment: `mongod.exe --dbpath "C:/Users/Пользователь/AppData/Local/MyPrg"`